# Find a limit of recursion sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, recursion

I have to find a limit of recursion sequence $a_{n}=-\frac{3}{8}(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$ where $a_1=1, a_0=0$. I wrote few of first terms of sequence: $0,1,-\frac38,\frac{15}{64},-\frac{57}{8^3}...$ My idea was to prove that $|a_n|\leq(\frac12)^{n-1}$ what would mean that the limit is 0. I was trying to do that by induction but I can't do it. Everything was falling apart at second step (I tried to use triangle inequality but it's not good enough). Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but it may be easier to show that $|a_{n+1}|<|a_n|$ by induction and the result will follow.

Comment: Hint: $|a_n|\leq r^{n}$ holds if $3(1+r) \leq 8r^{2}$. This is true if $r\in (0,1)$ is close enough to $1$.

Comment: What was your problem with the induction?

Comment: @Lereu Induction fails for $(\frac 1 2)^{n-1}$

Comment: Thank you, @geetha290krm. Now I see that my estimation was wrong

Comment: $(0.9)^{n}$ works, for example.

Comment: Now in the second step of induction i ended up with $|a_{n+1}|\leq \frac38(|a_n|+|a_{n-1}|)\leq \frac38(\frac78)^n+\frac38|a_{n-1}|$ and I don't know how to proceed. Is the triangle inequality too rough or how can i fix it?

Comment: With $(0,9)^n$ it's the same issue

Comment: I am surprised that you have difficulty with $(0,9)^{n}$. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Claim: $|a_i|\leq (0.9)^{i}$ for $i \geq 2$.

$a_2=-\frac  3 8 (1+0)$, so $|a_2| \leq (0.9)^{2}$.

Supppose $|a_i|\leq (0.9)^{i}$ for $2 \leq i <n$. Then, $|a_n|\le \frac 3 8 ((0.9)^{n-1}+(0.9)^{n-2})=\frac 3 8 (0.9)^{n-2}(0.9+1) $. Note that $\frac  38 (1.9)<(0.9)^{2}$. Hence, $|a_n|\le(0.9)^{n}$.